# converting dates using as.POSIXct

Tags: r, date

I want to generate a vector of 21 years starting from 1990 to 2010. I am using the `as.POSIXct` function as follows

```
time=as.POSIXct("1990-01-01", tz="GMT")+0:20*3600*(24*365)
```

and i get the following answer

```
 [1] "1990-01-01 GMT" "1991-01-01 GMT" "1992-01-01 GMT" "1992-12-31 GMT" "1993-12-31 GMT" "1994-12-31 GMT"
 [7] "1995-12-31 GMT" "1996-12-30 GMT" "1997-12-30 GMT" "1998-12-30 GMT" "1999-12-30 GMT" "2000-12-29 GMT"
[13] "2001-12-29 GMT" "2002-12-29 GMT" "2003-12-29 GMT" "2004-12-28 GMT" "2005-12-28 GMT" "2006-12-28 GMT"
[19] "2007-12-28 GMT" "2008-12-27 GMT" "2009-12-27 GMT"
```

which ends in 2009 instead of 2010 as desired.

Can anyone help and if possible on how to generate years without the month and dates, only the years alone using `as.POSIXct` function?

Comment: You do realise not every year has 365 days, right?

Comment: yes, and that actually creates a problem. see the method provide by orizon below. it works better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that only requires you to specify the year range you want:

```
time <- as.POSIXct(paste0(1990:2010, "-01-01"), tz = "GMT")
```

I have assumed you want 1 January each year, not some close approximation.

Now if you only want to show the year you can do something like:

```
format(time, "%Y")
 #[1] "1990" "1991" "1992" "1993" "1994" "1995" "1996" "1997" "1998" "1999" "2000" "2001" "2002" "2003"
 #[15] "2004" "2005" "2006" "2007" "2008" "2009" "2010"
```

Comment: yes, it solves the problem, but was wondering what if i only want the year without the time and dates and months.

Comment: @jonestates Do you mean that you only want to print the year? POSIXct objects record a date-time in seconds, so if you are using POSIXct it is inevitable that the month, day and time are stored as well as the year.

Comment: @jonestats I have added a way to show only the year to my answer.

Comment: I will stick to the earlier solution coz i want to do a variogram and the format(time, "%Y") will not be accepted. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
ISOdate(1990:2010,1,1)
```

Comment: this solves the problem, what if  i dont want the month and time to appear? just the year?

Comment: See the comment from @orizon and the update to that answer using `format()`.  If that is all you want though, you could just do `1990:2010` and skip the step of creating the date...

Comment: I will stick to the earlier solution coz i want to do a variogram and the format(time, "%Y") will not be accepted. thanks for the help.