# Date Conversion mm/dd/yyy hh:mm:ss to yyyy-mm-dd in R

Tags: r, date

I would like to convert the data frame

`12/31/2012 23:49:18

 12/30/2012 20:27:17

12/29/2012 20:21:24`

to

`2012-12-31

 2013-12-30

 2013-12-29`

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Does it have to be a date object or can it be a character string?

Comment: Yo u should use `ymd()` function from `lubridate` package `DF$your.date=ymd(DF$your.date)`

Comment: see e.g. [**this Q&A**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14888511/1478381)...

Comment: This worked for me `df$Date = as.Date(df$Date_Sub, format('%m/%d/%Y'))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to get your dates in a `"POSIXt"` class and then convert to a `"Date"`, forcing the timezone to avoid issues during conversion:

```
dates <- as.POSIXct(c("12/31/2012 23:49:18", "12/30/2012 20:27:17", 
                      "12/29/2012 20:21:24"),
                    format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
as.Date(dates)

R> as.Date(dates)
[1] "2012-12-31" "2012-12-30" "2012-12-29"
```

Another way is to format `dates` (as created above) to the correct format you need:

```
R> format(dates, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
[1] "2012-12-31" "2012-12-30" "2012-12-29"
```

Comment: Couldn't you just create the dates like this?: `as.POSIXct( "12/31/2012 23:49:18" , format = "%m/%d/%Y" , tz = "UTC" )` ignoring the time component?

Comment: @SimonO101 You could, as `strptime` indicates, but I prefer the approach I used and go to a proper Date object rather than mess about with time zones etc just for the dates part.

Comment: This worked for me  `df$Date = as.Date(df$Date_Sub, format('%m/%d/%Y'))`